# Listen to all interrupts with Python

Tags: python, operating-system, interrupt

I'm attempting to debug/observe what is happening to a DigitalOcean droplet when it is destroyed. I essentially want to see what (if any) interrupts are sent when I click the "destroy" button in the dashboard.

The Python docs have https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal, but you have to listen for specific interrupts. I don't know what interrupts will occur, so I'd like to listen to **every** interrupt and simply log out what happens.

Is there any way to do something like:

```
def my_handler(signum, frame):
    print(signum)

signal.signal(my_handler)
```

and listen for every interrupt without having to register each individually?

Comment: I think there may be some confusion here. Interrupts are a CPU/hardware level concept. The signal library, on the other hand, deals with POSIX signals (such as SIGKILL) that happen on the process level. I have no idea what is a "DigitalOcean droplet". Is it an executable that runs in its own process? If so, signals may be relevant.

Comment: Ah you are correct. I was using the two interchangeably. What I really want is to be able to listen for ANY type of signal (hardware, POSIX, or otherwise) that tells me this droplet is going to be going away immanently. A droplet is the DigitalOcean equivalent of an Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Ok, according to some quick googling, the droplet is a Linux virtual machine, managed by a hypervisor. I'd guess that on the destroy command, the hypervisor simply shuts the VM down. This probably causes SIGTERM and then SIGKILL to be sent to each process running inside the VM. However since I'm not familiar with DigitalOcean, this is just a guess.